spring boot with mongodb pagination
I paginated my collection in Spring Data Mongodb with this codes:
controller;
@GetMapping("/v1/get-all")
    public List<UserEntity> getAll(@RequestParam Integer page, @RequestParam Integer size) {
        return service.getAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));
    }

service;
 public List<UserEntity> getAll(Pageable pageable){
        return userRepository.findAll(pageable).stream().toList();
    }

but result is like this;
for the first request than page is 0 and size is 5
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for the second request than page is 1 and size is 5
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

just skip for one item.
How I can solve this problem?
I check the documentation of Spring Boot and Mongodb but found nothing.

The return type of getAll method in the contoller and service should be returned as Page Type not the List Type.
Controller:-
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;

@GetMapping("/v1/get-all")
public Page<UserEntity> getAll(@RequestParam Integer page, @RequestParam Integer size) {
    return userService.getAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));
}

Service:-
public Page<UserEntity> getAll(Pageable pageable){
    return userRepository.findAll(pageable);
}

Repository:-
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Integer> {

    Page<UserEntity> findAll(Pageable pageable);

}

